# Python: How to write a dictionary of tuple values to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, tuples

How do I print the following dictionary into a csv file?

```
maxDict = {'test1': ('alpha', 2), 'test2': ('gamma', 2)}
```

So, that the output CSV looks as follows:

```
test1, alpha, 2
test2, gamma, 2
```

Comment: Hey siva! I see you got your answers, but next time please let us know what you tried yourself instead of asking others to write your code. In python there is a library for almost any common task. The one to write a csv file is named csv. That should be easy to find. And in case you where not stuck there but with extracting key and value pairs from dictionary your question should reflect that in some way. That said, have fun on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import csv
with open("data.csv", "wb") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows((k,) + v for k, v in maxDict.iteritems())
```

Comment: what is being written into a csv using the `writerows` method? is it a list? tuple?

Comment: The generator expression in the above code feeds tuples to `writerows()`, but you could also use lists if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

```
maxDict = {'test1': ('alpha', 2), 'test2': ('gamma', 2)}
csvData = []
for col1, (col2, col3) in maxDict.iteritems():
  csvData.append("%s, %s, %s" % (col1, col2, col3))
f = open('test.csv', 'w')
f.write("\n".join(csvData))
f.close()
```

Comment: I updated my unpacking of the tuple to make it more readable.