# How to write csv files by Python?

Tags: python, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python csv: save results to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345336/python-csv-save-results-to-csv-file)
>   [Python: How to write a dictionary of tuple values to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530619/python-how-to-write-a-dictionary-of-tuple-values-to-a-csv-file)

Previously I use this to write the results line by line to a text file, in each line, values are separated by tab

```
fd_out.write("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\n" % (obj["name"],obj["count"],obj["age"],obj["params"]["country"])
```

but now I want to have CSV output instead, how am I suppose to write the code?
Just like this or should I import CSV and use some other method?
Sorry, I am quite a newbie of programming...

```
fd_out.write("%s,%d,%d,%s\n" % (obj["name"],obj["count"],obj["age"],obj["params"]["country"])
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should work for basic data, but some problem may arise in some cases, if you have commas in your data.

The `csv` module takes care of that problem, as well as any similar problems. The usage is quite easy, you would just do :

```
writer = csv.writer(fd_out)
writer.writerows((obj["name"],obj["count"],obj["age"],obj["params"]["country"]))
```

Note the double parens, we pass a tuple because `writerows` except an iterable. Don't hesitate to check [the doc](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) if you want more info.

Answer (score 1):

"CSV" is not a standard, and even though "CSV" literally means "comma-separated values", using tab as the delimiter is just as common as a comma, if not more common.  See also wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

To cater for CSV fields containing the delimiter (i.e. tab or comma), it's common to quote the data, i.e. with double quotes.  There is no standard - sometimes only data fields that contains the delimiter is quoted.  In the example below all fields will be quoted.

With the csv built-in library it's quite easy to modify the format of the output CSV file as you like.

```
import csv

objs = [{'name': 'knut', 'age': 74, 'count': 13},
        {'name': 'lydia', 'age': 14, 'count': 3}]

with open("/tmp/example.csv", "w") as outfile:
    ## Ordering of the fields in the CSV output
    headers = ['name', 'age', 'count']

    ## although "CSV" stands for "comma separated values", 
    ## it's quite common to use other delimiters i.e. TAB
    ## and still call it "CSV".
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    ## it's common in CSV to have the headers on the first line
    writer.writerow(headers)

    ## Write out the data
    for obj in objs:
        writer.writerow([obj[key] for key in headers])
```

This example also demonstrates condensed list operations in python ... `[obj[key] for key in headers]` means "give me the list of obj[key] for all keys in header".